# Base address and offsets

Tags: address, offset, pointer

I've watched a video about finding out static addresses with pointers

Here is an example:

```
OFFSET 0
01DE15B4

OFFSET 14
01DE15D0

OFFSET 378
BASE ADDRESS> 01DE8058
```

and the person said, that

> After finding the static base address we don't need the other addresses (leading to the base address) just the offsets.

so according to him this would be enough:

```
OFFSET 0


OFFSET 14


OFFSET 378
BASE ADDRESS> 01DE8058
```

So basically I just put it any address and add these offsets so I always get to this base address?

What are the preconditions to get with these offsets to that exact address?

Comment: Is this about Cheat Engine? You should probably ask the author because the addresses do not line up so I have no idea what he means.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky yes he refers to CE, is he probably refering to c++ 'readprocess'?

Comment: sorry, still not making sense to me.

Comment: My name is not weird! It's the int value of my fullname, hf cracking it :) @FarewellStackExchange Okay I will try another Forum then